# How to understand the English preposition "over" in Computer Network?

Tags: network-programming, protocols, network-protocols

well..

I'm from a non-English speaking country.

I need to use DTCP-IP in my work, which the full-name is Digital Transmission Content Protection over Internet Protocol.
What confused me is the word "over".

The network model is:

-------------------------------[ The Transportation Layer ]

[ Header of Internet Protocol ][ Content from The Transportation Layer ]

The problem is
which part should be handled?
and how to interpret the word "over" in this field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Over in this context means "using".. You watch a television show OVER the television cable, you make a phone call OVER the phone line, so it's a protocol that protects content as it transmits it across the internet.